# Returning C string from boost::shared_ptr<string>

Tags: c++, c

I'm wrapping some C++ code in functions in order to make the C++ methods available in C.

The C++ API methods return `boost::shared_ptr<T>` objects usually. My exported function in C++ looks like this:

```
extern "C" const char *Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string(
    Hazelcast_Client_t *hazelcastClient,
    const char *mapName,
    int key,
    char** errptr
) {
    IMap<int, string> map = hazelcastClient->client->getMap<int, string>(mapName);
    boost::shared_ptr<string> value = map.get(key);

    string *strValue = value.get();

    return strValue->c_str();
}
```

My C client code looks like this:

```
const char *stringValue = NULL;
stringValue = Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string(client, "int_string_map", 10, &err);

printf("got value from map %s\n", stringValue);
```

It works in so far, as `printf` outputs the correct value on stdout. However, checking the code with `valgrind`, it shows an invalid read error. So I suppose I'm doing something wrong with passing the pointers around, but I can't really understand what's the problem.

Can I avoild having to `strdup` the value of the `boost::shared_ptr<string>` or is that what i need to do?

Here the `valgrind` error:

```
==20635== Invalid read of size 1
==20635==    at 0x10034C6BF: strlen (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==20635==    by 0x1006136E7: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==20635==    by 0x10063C35C: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==20635==    by 0x10061201D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==20635==    by 0x10060FEB7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==20635==    by 0x100001E6A: main (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==  Address 0x100de9c41 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==20635==    at 0x10034B2F7: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==20635==    by 0x1000068BF: void boost::checked_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100006888: boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::dispose() (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x1000054AD: boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100005449: boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100005414: boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x1000053F8: boost::shared_ptr<int>::~shared_ptr() (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100004054: boost::shared_ptr<int>::~shared_ptr() (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x10000347F: Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100001E54: main (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==  Block was alloc'd at
==20635==    at 0x10034AEBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==20635==    by 0x10038E7DD: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==20635==    by 0x1000B8C80: hazelcast::client::serialization::pimpl::DataInput::readUTF() (DataInput.cpp:147)
==20635==    by 0x1000E367F: std::__1::auto_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > hazelcast::client::serialization::pimpl::SerializationService::toObject<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(hazelcast::client::serialization::pimpl::Data const&) (SerializationService.cpp:590)
==20635==    by 0x10000659D: std::__1::auto_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > hazelcast::client::proxy::ProxyImpl::toObject<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(hazelcast::client::serialization::pimpl::Data const&) (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100006413: std::__1::auto_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > hazelcast::client::proxy::ProxyImpl::toObject<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::auto_ptr<hazelcast::client::serialization::pimpl::Data>) (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x10000484B: hazelcast::client::IMap<int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::get(int const&) (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x10000338F: Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
==20635==    by 0x100001E54: main (in ./hazelcastCClientTest)
```

EDIT: Question from the comments was `what is the desired effect?`. My initial goal was to return the string to the C caller without any additional memory allocation, but it seems the usual way is to allocate another string in memory and return that or `NULL` to the caller.

EDIT 2: The reason I want to *avoid unneeded memory allocation* was basically because i remembered an article from Ayende https://ayende.com/blog/161281/robs-sprint-the-cost-of-getting-data-from-leveldb about how much copying happens until one can get a string from leveldb through C/C# bindings.

I wanted to avoid the same pitfall, but I think it's only possible to minimize additional memory allocation.

Comment: What is the desired effect? Do you want the caller to free the memory? Or do you want it to work some other way? If you want the caller to `free` the string, `strdup` is the best solution. If you want the pointer to stay valid to the next invocation of this function, maybe make the `shared_ptr` static. Maybe you want the caller to pass in a buffer and a maximum length?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thats a good question, I would like to avoid having to allocate memory myself in order to avoid unnecessary memory usage, but I also want an easy to use API. I tried to look at how leveldb does it https://github.com/emnl/leveldb-c-example/blob/master/leveldb_example.c it seems like the caller is not responsible for freeing the memory? This seems what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: leveldb_get returns a pointer to a string that is created with malloc and filled with memcpy.  It has to be freed sometime - I think the caller is meant to do it.  According to the header file: `/* Returns NULL if not found. A malloc()ed array otherwise.
Stores the length of the array in vallen. */
extern char leveldb_get(
leveldb_t* db,
const leveldb_readoptions_t* options,
const char* key, size_t keylen,
size_t* vallen,
char** errptr);`

Comment: I have seen it done like this: you malloc the memory/strdup the string and keep a pointer to it in a vector and then when you are done you free everything in the vector.  The user gets the pointer but doesn't need to free it.  It does require memory allocation though.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I just read the comment on top of the leveldb file yesterday, but I must have forgotten already, you are right. I don't have enough experience yet with exporting C++ APIs to C, but if another memory allocation is the usual procedure, then I will implement it like this and check the leveldb implementation more. But isn't the C API then automatically slower then the C++ one because of additional in-memory copying?

Comment: @Max: "isn't the C API then automatically slower" - the C++ one can easily partake in reference counting, which is needed to get equivalent performance with some lifetime guarantee.  You could approximate this in C, and thereby get similar performance: dynamically allocate a shared pointer and giving the C client code a pointer to that as well as the textual string content, then the C code would call some other "release" function to delete the shared pointer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I updated the question with a link to an a bit dated article from Ayende. He describes the problems he had with too many memory allocations in bindings for level_db. https://ayende.com/blog/161281/robs-sprint-the-cost-of-getting-data-from-leveldb But I'm not entirely sure if this can be actually avoided.

Comment: @Max: if you want even closer-to-C++ performance, you could create a C `struct` with alignment and size sufficient to store a shared pointer - so the C caller can allocate space for that on the stack and pass a pointer to it to `Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string`, inside which you'd placement-`new` a shared pointer in there.  You'd still need another call from C into C++ to invoke the `shared_ptr` destructor later, decrementing the reference count.  That's a bit hard to maintain though - you could use a static assertion that the struct was the same size as a shared pointer; fast but ugly.

Comment: @TonyD sounds interesting, otoh I want to keep it simple as much as possible. I actually plan on open sourcing this project https://github.com/maxbeutel/hazelcast-c-client so I want to provide good performance but also keep the "surprises" in the implementation as few as possible :-)

Comment: @Max: well, you could `strdup` for ease of use, and offer a non-copying/reference-counted alternative for anyone who finds that's not fast enough....

Comment: @TonyD thanks for the idea, that sounds like a good approach that get's me unstuck for now. So this SO question is actually not valid anymore, but the discussion in the comments here has been super helpful.

Comment: @Max: if you've the energy, you could post/accept your own answer summarising/illustrating the solution you end up using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering what I actually want to achieve (easy yet safe C-API), I decided to return a newly allocated string to the client. The final solution (for now) looks like this:

```
extern "C" int Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string(
    Hazelcast_Client_t *hazelcastClient,
    const char *mapName,
    int key,
    char **value,
    char** errptr
) {
    assert(hazelcastClient != NULL);
    assert(hazelcastClient->client != NULL);

    assert(mapName != NULL);

    assert(value != NULL);

    try {
        auto map = hazelcastClient->client->getMap<int, string>(mapName);
        boost::shared_ptr<string> sharedPtr = map.get(key);

        string *ptr = sharedPtr.get();

        if (ptr == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }

        *value = strdup(ptr->c_str());
        return 0;
    } catch(const std::runtime_error& re) {
        saveMessageInErrPtr(errptr, re.what());
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        saveMessageInErrPtr(errptr, ex.what());
    } catch(...) {
        saveUnknownErrorOccurredMessageInErrPtr(errptr);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I decided to use the return value of the function to indicate success/failure state, in addition to providing an error message in `errptr`.

The client code looks like this:

```
char *stringValue = NULL;

if (Hazelcast_Map_get_int_string(client, "int_string_map", 10, &stringValue, &err) != 0) {
    printf("ERR Map get failed: %s\n", err);
    Hazelcast_free(err); err = NULL;
} else {
    printf("got value from map %s\n", stringValue);
    free(stringValue);
}
```

I think this is easy enough to use while still providing error handling.